# Tmux - Hotkey (or command) to move to marked pane

Tags: tmux

There are hotkeys to move to the last pane (<kbd>prefix</kbd>-<kbd>;</kbd>) and the last window (<kbd>prefix</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd>). Is there a hotkey (or a command that can be bound to a hotkey) to move to a marked pane (and move to its window if it is not on the current window)? If not, is there some way of identifying a specific window and returning to it via hotkey without using the pane number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good question. Do you mean *the* marked pane, or do you have your own idea of "marked pane"?

If the former, you can mark the pane with `C-b m`, and use the `{marked}` target to go to it

```
bind Q switch-client -t'{marked}'
```

If you are want your own marked pane, or you are using an old tmux version without the marked pane, you could use a user option to store the marked pane. For example, bind a key to save the ID of the active pane, something like:

```
bind Q run "tmux set -g @mymarkedpane #{pane_id}"
```

Then a key switch to it with a key binding like:

```
bind W run "tmux switch-client -t#{@mymarkedpane}"
```

If you want a marked pane for each sesson rather than just one, remove `-g` from the `set` command.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer, that solves it. I meant _the_ marked pane, so the first solution is all I need. The second solution is great for future reference though, I'll work that into my workflow over time. Is there somewhere this kind of thing is documented? I couldn't find something like the {marked} target in the man page. Edit: I just realised you're the tmux developer - thanks for a great piece of software!

Comment: Yes I just realised that {marked} is missing from the man page, it was only when I went to add it to the code I realised it was missing. I am going to fix that. Thanks!

Comment: Actually it is already in the man page, just not in the tables - `...'{marked}' (alternative form ‘~’) to specify the marked pane (see select-pane -m)`.

Comment: I don't know how I missed it earlier, but you're right it's already there, below the tables. Thanks again.